# Multiple APNS providers with the same certificate

Tags: ios, architecture, apple-push-notifications

I have many private servers and each server can serve multiple iOS clients.

I would like to use APNS notifications for my app for each of these iOS devices and I'm trying to find an architectural paradigm for the provider I should create.

Should I create one provider that serves each of these private servers and clients or should I use for each server a corresponding provider? Does this depend on the certificate I'm using? For instance could I use the same certificate to multiple providers or only one is allowed?

I haven't found something explicitly on the site of Apple, but I can infer from the fact that since only one certificate is provided from Apple Developer Site, I could use it in multiple providers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use same certificate on multiple provider instances for same app. Infact as per 'Best Practices for Managing Connections' by Apple, "You can establish multiple connections to APNs servers to improve performance. When you send a large number of remote notifications, distribute them across connections to several server endpoints"

So you can use multiple connections from one provider instance, as well as, multiple connections from multiple provider instances using the same certificate.

Regards,
_Ayush